# unable to to locate package apt-fast

Tags: apt, apt-fast

This is what I tried:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apt-fast/stable
$ sudo apt-get update
..........something something.........  
.................................................................  
.................................................................   
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/apt-fast/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/apt-fast/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I then tried

```
$ sudo apt-get install apt-fast
```

but it says:

```
Reading package lists... Done       
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done  
E: Unable to locate package apt-fast
```

Answer (score 4):

add it as you did before and then :

open system settings-> software updates-> other software

look for the ppa that was added. Click it and then select edit. Change the distribution from trusty to saucy. Exit and open a terminal.

sudo apt-get update

and then

sudo apt-get install apt-fast

Comment: It worked but what is the difference between trusy and saucy? Apologies if it is a dumb questions

Comment: They're different version of Ubuntu. Trusty is version 14.04; saucy is version 13.10. In general, you should stick to the repository that your machine is using. In this specific case, I don't think there were any changes that would break things from 13.10 to 14.04.

Answer (score 3):

The PPA manager hasn't uploaded any packages for Trusty yet (as evidenced by the two "Failed to fetch" errors). Therefore, `apt` can't find `apt-fast` because the package isn't available yet.

You might want to contact the PPA maintainer and ask him to upload a version for Trusty.

I've made a version for Trusty, which you can use from [my PPA](https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/ubuntu/myppa).

Comment: Iam just a beginner. Thanks for reply. But do you know any method to install apt-fast. As it increases speed of installations.

Comment: Looks like there still isn't a version packaged for Trusty. You can install it manually using the "Manual" instructions on the apt-fast project page: https://github.com/ilikenwf/apt-fast

Comment: I made a version for Trusty. I'll add the link in my answer.